# SOLR merge fields from multiple data sources

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, multiple-databases, dataimporthandler

I have two databases which contains different attributes about a person. 
Database 'A' may contain fields like age, location.
Database 'B' may contain fields like occupation, education.

```
Database 'A' users                     Database 'B' users
Charlie-18, California                 Charlie-Engineer, Masters
Amanda-21, Nevada                      Darwin-Teacher, Bachelors
```

I want an index with documents-

```
<doc>
  <str>Charlie   </str>`
  <int>18        </int>
  <str>California</str>
  <str>Engineer  </str>
  <str>Masters   </str>
<doc>

<doc>
  <str>Darwin   </str>
  <int>         </int>
  <str>         </str>
  <str>Teacher  </str>
  <str>Bacherlor</str>
<doc>

<doc>
  <str>Amanda    </str>
  <int>21        </int>
  <str>Nevada    </str>
  <str>          </str>
  <str>          </str>
<doc>
```

I know I can use multiple database and nest entities like here-
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Multiple_DataSources

But this will get me on Charlie and Amanda's information if I nest Database B entities inside Database A.

How to get attributes for all available persons in either of the databases?
How can I configure this?

Comment: I assume (given the link) that you need a solution using DataImportHandler?

Comment: I guess Dataimporthandler would just be pulling the data. but how should I configure solr to get a union of the data from these two sources.